# Java JApplet render issues

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, japplet

I have a problem with JApplet. The code was working just fine, but when I converted it from JFrame to JApplet, the render part stopped working properly. Basicly what I'm trying to do is simplistic draw app. When launching applet, half of time repaint() is not working (There is no gray background; you have to put mouse over button for it to update its color etc), furtheremore the pixel rendering part is not shown up at all. Here's the code:

The Frame class (JApplet)

```
  package painter;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Frame extends JApplet {

public JPanel panel;
private JButton plus, minus, buttonColor;
private int scaleSize;
private JLabel labelScale;
private final Timer updateTimer;
private static boolean painting = false;
public static Color currentColor;
public static int mode = 0;
// 0 = draw; 1 = setcolor; 2 = erase

private ArrayList<Pixel> pixelArray;

public Frame() {

    pixelArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 8; j++) {
            pixelArray.add(new Pixel(i, j));
        }
    }

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel = new JPanel() {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            //g.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);  <- test if fillRect works at all. Yus it does.
            for (int i = 0; i < pixelArray.size(); i++) {
                pixelArray.get(i).render(g);
            }
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
            g.dispose();
        }

    };

    //panel.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 800);
    //add(panel);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    //panel.setLayout(null);
    //panel.setOpaque(true);

    //panel.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    currentColor = Color.yellow;

    buttonColor = new JButton("Choose color");
    buttonColor.setBounds(10, 10, 128, 64);
    buttonColor.setBackground(currentColor);
    buttonColor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            currentColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "JColorChooser Sample", Color.gray);
        }

    });

    updateTimer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            buttonColor.setBackground(currentColor);
            repaint();
        }

    });
    updateTimer.start();
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            painting = true;
        }
    });
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            painting = false;
        }
    });

    panel.add(buttonColor);

    repaint();
}

public static boolean getPaint() {
    return painting;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Frame();
}
}
```

And here is the Pixel class:

```
package painter;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Pixel {

private Color color;
private int size;
private int x, y, relativex, relativey;

public Pixel(int relx, int rely) {
    color = new Color(0x999999, false);
    size = 32;
    x = relx * size + 64;
    y = rely * size + 64;

}

public boolean mouseOver() {
    Point pos, mousepos;
    pos = new Point(x, y);
    mousepos = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    if ((mousepos.x > pos.x)
            && (mousepos.x < pos.x + size)
            && (mousepos.y > pos.y)
            && (mousepos.y < pos.y + size)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(color);
    if (mouseOver() && Frame.getPaint()) {

        if (Frame.mode == 0) {
            color = Frame.currentColor;
        }
        if (Frame.mode == 1) {
            Frame.currentColor = color;
        }
        if (Frame.mode == 2) {
            color = new Color(0xffffffff, true);
        }
    }

    g.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
    if (mouseOver()) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(x, y, size - 1, size - 1);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.drawRect(x + 1, y + 1, size - 3, size - 3);
    }
    //g.fillRect(10, 10, 250, 250);
}

}
```

Comment: *"..but when I converted it from JFrame to JApplet"* *Why* did you convert it from frame to applet rather than launch the (working) frame from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)?

Comment: *"..furtheremore the.."* Whoa up there.  SO is not a 'one-stop help desk' but a Q&A site.  Speaking of which, what is your specific *question*?  Also for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson This project was supposed to be an applet from very start, but I made it as JFrame first since it`s easier to test and less buggy. As of furthermore part I just wanted to provide evidence that render is not working, and my only question is why.

Comment: Don't call your custom class `Frame`. There is an AWT component by that name so it is confusing. Use a more descriptive name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a stab in the dark, don't call `Graphics#dipose` on a `Graphics` context you did not create yourself explicitly

Apart from the fact the the `Graphics` context is a shared resource, used by all the components that might need to be painted within a given paint cycle, it can also prevent what ever was painted to it to be displayed on some platforms

In 15 years of professional development, I've never had reason to call `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();`. I doubt it'll make that big a difference, I'm just saying

Comment: I found the solution: MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation() just messes everything up for some reason. Yet I feel your tips were helpful thus I`ll give you best answer.

Comment: Don't use `MouseInfo`, use a `MouseListener` or `MouseMotionListener`

Answer (score 0):

Java applets provide us with these methods

[here] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/appletMethods.html

the method

```
public void paint(Graphics g){}
```

is used as alternative of

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){}
```

of swing.

Comment: Didn`t mention, but I tried everything: paint, paintComponent, hell even paint method inside JApplet. Doesn`t solve the problem.

Comment: Actually, you have that kind of backward. Top level containers, like JApplet, only have a paint method, this is kind of deliberate, as most Swing top level containers also contain other components, JRootPane, content lane and possibly a glass pane, so it makes little sense to provide a paintComponnent method, as it will be covered over by other things. Components extending from JComponent have, amongst other paint method, paintCompnent, which provides a means by which painting can re easily be customized

Answer (score -1):

Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html for the recommended way to perform custom painting of swing components